# Sonarqube on Browser in Linux

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have installed and configured the sonarqube on the server and created a symlink with systemd/systemctl, it properly running in terminal without any error but not running on browser even with default port. The version i have tried is 8.71 and 9, but in both it doesn't work, i have configured the postgres credentials and all in **"sonar.properties"**
but even after anything it doesn't work,

> sonarqube@sonar2020:~/sonarqube-8.3.1.34397$
> bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start\
>
> > ; Starting SonarQube... Started SonarQube. sonarqube@sonar2020:~/sonarqube-8.3.1.34397$ bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh
> > status SonarQube is running (12957).
> > sonarqube@sonar2020:~/sonarqube-8.3.1.34397$  sudo nano
> > /etc/systemd/system/sonar.service
> > sonarqube@sonar2020:~/sonarqube-8.3.1.34397$ sudo systemctl enable
> > sonar Created symlink
> > /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sonar.service →
> > /etc/systemd/system/sonar.service.
> > sonarqube@sonar2020:~/sonarqube-8.3.1.34397$ sudo systemctl start
> > sonar.service  sonarqube@sonar2020:~/sonarqube-8.3.1.34397$ sudo
> > systemctl status sonar.service  ● sonar.service - SonarQube service
> > Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sonar.service; enabled; vendor
> > preset: enabled)    Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-11-22
> > 09:12:15 UTC; 1s ago   Process: 13574
> > ExecStop=/home/sonarqube/sonarqube-8.3.1.34397/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh
> > stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)   Process: 13634
> > ExecStart=/home/sonarqube/sonarqube-8.3.1.34397/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh
> > start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 13697 (wrapper)
> > Tasks: 19 (limit: 4915)    CGroup: /system.slice/sonar.service
> > ├─13697 /home/sonarqube/sonarqube-8.3.1.34397/bin/linux-x86-64/./wrapper
> > /home/sonarqube/sonarqube-8.3.1.34397/bin/linux-x86-64/../../conf/wrapper.conf
> > wrapper.syslog.ident=SonarQube
> > wrapper.pidfile=/home/sonarqube/sonarqube-8.3.1.34397/bin/linux-x86-
> > └─13702 java -Dsonar.wrapped=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms8m -Xmx32m -Djava.library.path=./lib -classpath ../../lib/jsw/wrapper-3.2.3.jar:../../lib/common/picocontainer-2.15.jar:../../lib/common/lucene-join-7.7.2.jar:../../lib/common/sonar-db-mig
>
> Nov 22 09:12:14 sonar2020 systemd[1]: sonar.service: Scheduled restart
> job, restart counter is at 3. Nov 22 09:12:14 sonar2020 systemd[1]:
> Stopped SonarQube service. Nov 22 09:12:14 sonar2020 systemd[1]:
> Starting SonarQube service... Nov 22 09:12:14 sonar2020
> sonar.sh[13634]: Starting SonarQube... Nov 22 09:12:15 sonar2020
> sonar.sh[13634]: Started SonarQube. Nov 22 09:12:15 sonar2020
> systemd[1]: Started SonarQube service.

Now whenever i try to open it on browser, it shows connection refused. How can it be refused when all ports are open in local??

Comment: Did you check the firewall (client and server side) or if the port is open `sudo ss -tulpn | grep LISTEN` ?

Comment: yes i did, it's just too stubborn to not to listen on ports i assigned to sonar

Comment: netstat -tulpen | grep 9000.  No response of this